# How to resize the superview to conform to the subviews constraints

Tags: ios, swift, view, autolayout, constraints

I created a custom UIView class where I create 2 UILabels and 1 UIImageView. I set the constraints for each element. Since the Labels will hold dynamic text each view will have a different height. How can I resize the height of the view? the constraints (top to bottom) are:

```
View Top > 16 > Label1 > 8 > ImageView > 8 > Label2 > 16 > View Bottom
```

The problem is: I have to initialize the UIView with a frame. and no matter what I try the view always uses the height of the frame given by initializing. And I cannot calculate the height of all elements and set a new frame because the labels habe sometimes 1 and sometimes 5 lines.

[This is how the view looks at runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqmmG.png)
[This is how its supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2pdf.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your layout is completely specified by constraints, you don't need a "real" frame to initialize the `UIView`. `CGRect.zero` is fine. The view will automatically resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize the view with a frame, but when setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` after initializing, the frame passed in becomes irrelevant. Therefore, you can do what @BallpointBen recommended in the comments and pass in `.zero`:

```
let newCustomView = CustomView(frame: .zero)
newCustomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// auto layout constraints should now determine height
```

Comment: it worked perfectly. thanks. I have written a bunch of lines and nothing has changed. At least now I know how to achieve this in other projects :D